# Spring Security: How configure correctly CSRF for Ajax security control filter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working with `Spring Security`

The app has enabled the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/css/**", "/resources/images/**", "/resources/jquery/**", "/resources/js/**").permitAll()
        ... more URLs to intercept  
        .antMatchers("/notification**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/ajax/notification**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        .and()
        .csrf()
        ...
```

Observe `CSRF` is applied. For a form the following is used:

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}"
    method="post">
<input type="submit"
    value="Log out" />
<input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

It according [Form Submissions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-form)

The app works fine how is expected, it intercepts any URL prior to load/render a `jsp` page and ask for the login control how is expected, if the user has logged the control about authorization is applied how is expected too. Therefore all is working with `CSRF` how is suggested.

Until here all is Ok.

I added ajax through `jQuery` and because it works with an URL, therefore I need apply the `CSRF` control for that URL too.

That's why above appears:

- `.antMatchers("/ajax/notification**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")`

Now, I want get the *expected* **HTTP error code and message** when `CSRF` is applied to the ajax URL `"/ajax/notification"` *and* the `CSRF` headers were **not** send.

The js ajax code is:

```
    $.getJSON(
            "/projectname-01/ajax/notification",  
            function(data, textStatus, req) {

                console.log("data: " + data);
                console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("req: " + req)

                console.log("data: " + data);
                console.log(data.content + " " + data.date);

                $("#single").empty();
                $("#single").append(data.content + " " + data.date);

                $("#multiple").append(data.content + " " + data.date)
                              .append("<br/>");

            }
    )
```

**Note**: The URL needs to be `/projectname-01/ajax/notification`, the `projectname-01` is mandatory, if I remove that, I get the `404`. It does not work even if `./ajax/notification` is used (observe the dot).

**Problem**: The code works fine, I mean, the Ajax call happens to the server without any problem, I am expecting some error, it because the code is **not** using the `CRSF` requeriments for ajax.

It according from:

- [Ajax and JSON Requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax)
- [The csrfMetaTags Tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#the-csrfmetatags-tag)

Thus, such as either:

```
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

or

```
<sec:csrfMetaTags />
```

and of course the js code working with:

`_csrf_parameter`, `_csrf_header` etc.

Then the expected HTTP error code and message is need it for testing and production purposes

Thus, what is missing? or what is the problem?

**Headers**: how was requested below the HTTP headers:

From Opera

```
General
  Request URL:http://localhost:8080/security-01/ajax/notification
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:200 
  Remote Address:[::1]:8080
  Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
  HTTP/1.1 200
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: 0
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 00:14:20 GMT
Request Headers
  GET /security-01/ajax/notification HTTP/1.1
  Host: localhost:8080
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36 OPR/47.0.2631.80
  Referer: http://localhost:8080/security-01/tiles/notification/
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
  Cookie: JSESSIONID=9F2007DA3C8C683D26B8D17D85563140; jenkins-timestamper-offset=18000000
```

From Firefox

```
Request Headers
  Host: localhost:8080
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
  Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Referer: http://localhost:8080/security-01/tiles/notification/
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  Cookie: JSESSIONID=CF344E56DD03C4019DCA334CD38B73EC
  Connection: keep-alive

Response Header
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: 0
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 00:17:06 GMT
```

**Clarification**

According with `Spring Security Reference Documentation` we apply `CSRF` for a `JSP` page (submit form) **and** for `Ajax`, both work around with a `URL`. For the former I have already configured and works fine. The latter is the problem.

When I use `jQuery`'s `$.getJSON` call **without** send the special `CSRF data/headers` values (`<sec:csrfMetaTags />`, `meta[name='_csrf_parameter']` , etc), I mean from: [30.6 The csrfMetaTags Tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#the-csrfmetatags-tag) appears the following:

```
        // using JQuery to send an x-www-form-urlencoded request
        var data = {};
        data[csrfParameter] = csrfToken;
        data["name"] = "John";
        ...
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.org/do/something",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            ...
        });

        // using JQuery to send a non-x-www-form-urlencoded request
        var headers = {};
        headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.org/do/something",
            type: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            ...
        });
```

From above it sends the `CRSF` information either from `data` or `headers`. But in my code I am **not** sending that. Therefore I expect some special control and error reported through `Spring Security`

Thus with my current ajax code, through development in runtime (`Tomcat` running with the app), the call to the server happens and data is returned. Thus `Spring Security` did not *intercept* and throw an error due the *absence* of these `CRSF data/headers`.

Therefore thinking now for development and testing, if I create `@Test` methods where should fail because the `CSRF data/headers` values were **not** send. The `@Test` methods are going to fail because the call to the server happens without any *security* control.

Comment: I want receive the error message first, I am assuming I must receive that error because the headers were not send, once I get the expected message, then I add the suggested headers to resolve the error.

Comment: @ManuelJordan, can you please describe your problem more clearly?
 You're wondering why you're not getting csrf error when using your ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP `GET` request produces no error, because the CSRF token is only required for requests that update state, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#synchronizer-token-pattern):

> **18.2 Synchronizer Token Pattern**
>
> [...]
>   We can relax the expectations to only require the token for each HTTP request that updates state. This can be safely done since the same origin policy ensures the evil site cannot read the response. Additionally, we do not want to include the random token in HTTP GET as this can cause the tokens to be leaked.

and [`CsrfFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfFilter.html):

> Applies CSRF protection using a synchronizer token pattern. Developers are required to ensure that `CsrfFilter` is invoked for any request that allows state to change. Typically this just means that they should ensure their web application follows proper REST semantics (i.e. do not change state with the HTTP methods GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS).

To get a CSRF token you have to use HTTP `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` request.